# checking if the date and time is between in the given list of ranges in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table with notes and the time when i took the note. I have list of similar data that shows the meeting start and end dates.

I want to be able to know meting name against each note to understand which note came from which meeting.

Example:

Notes data:

```
Note ABC 01/22/2020 05:52:13
Note BVC 01/22/2020 08:08:19
Note TRT 05/10/2020 08:00:54
```

Meetings Data:

```
Production capacity planning 01/22/2020 04:00:00 | 01/22/2020 06:00:00

Planning and Goal setting 01/22/2020 07:30:00 | 01/22/2020 09:00:00
```

I want the corresponding meeting name in the first table to understand which note came from which meeting.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but you might want to consider using the `INDEX` or `VLOOKUP` functions with the last argument set to true. Keep in mind that date values are internally just numbers, and thus they can be compared for less than or greater than just fine.